# Input/ signup field on modal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, overlay

I am trying to add a signup/ input field on a modal but every time I click into the input field it just toggles off the modal

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button a").click(function(){
        $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);
       $(this).toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    });
});
$('.overlay').on('click', function(){
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);   
    $(".button a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    open = false;
});
```

http://codepen.io/kingatron/pen/qZLmjQ

How can I amend the jquery so I can still use the input field?

Answer (score 0):

Check for `input` as target when you click the overlay.

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function(e){
  if(e.target.id != "mce-EMAIL") {
    $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);   
    $(".button a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
    open = false;
  } 
});
```

This will check that if you click inside `input` on overlay then click action won't occur that is no toggle of overlay.

Refer this [pen](http://codepen.io/Bhumika107/pen/QNzOoJ).

Answer (score 0):

Your event is bubbling up from the element you clicked all the way through dom tree of elements located underneath where you clicked.  As such the

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function(){...});
```

handler is firing, and closing your overlay.

If you add an argument to the function definition, you can check the target of the event to identify the top element that was clicked on.

```
$('.overlay').on('click', function(){
  // check el.target to identify the element clicked on
  // to determine whether the overlay should be shown

  // if the element isn't the overlay div
  if (el.target != this)
  {
    // exit and return false to prevent the event from bubbling
    return false;
  }

  // otherwise hide the overlay...
  $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);   
  $(".button a").toggleClass('btn-open').toggleClass('btn-close');
  open = false;
});
```

Comment: Hi I just solved it - I changed $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200);  to $(".button a").fadeToggle(200);  and then changed the input type in the html. Thanks for taking the time to look at my question tho

Answer (score 0):

I changed $(".overlay").fadeToggle(200); to $(".button a").fadeToggle(200); and then changed the input type in the html. Thanks for taking the time to look at my question tho